# MongoDB and Pydantic: getting missing field "_id" when POST requesting

Tags: python, mongodb, pydantic

So I'm building an app to handle reservations and I'm getting this pydantic error saying "_id" is missing when sending a POST request. I want mongoDB to auto generate this "_id" so I shouldn't send it. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

The part about the PyObjectId:

```
def validate_object_id(v: Any) -> ObjectId:
if isinstance(v, ObjectId):
    return v
if ObjectId.is_valid(v):
    return ObjectId(v)
raise ValueError("Invalid ObjectId")


PyObjectId = Annotated[
    Union[str, ObjectId],
    AfterValidator(validate_object_id),
    PlainSerializer(lambda x: str(x), return_type=str),
    WithJsonSchema({"type": "string"}, mode="serialization"),
]
```

the Model class:

```
class ReservationModel(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(alias="_id")
    numberId: int = Field(...)
    status: str = Field(...)
    ...
```

the request:

```
async def create_reservation(reservation: ReservationModel = Body(...)):
    reservation = jsonable_encoder(reservation, by_alias=True)
    new_reservation = await db["reservations"].insert_one(reservation)
    created_reservation = await db["reservations"].find_one(
        {"_id": new_reservation.inserted_id}
    )
    return JSONResponse(status_code=201, content=created_reservation)
```

the error:

```
{
"detail": [
  {
    "type": "missing",
    "loc": [
      "body",
      "_id"
    ],
    ...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just added this to the POST request and it worked!

```
reservation.pop('_id')
```